# How to change a linked-list so that the last link is removed and the first one takes its place?

Tags: c

So I have been working with c code (for class). The linked list is made of structs linking to one another and I am trying to make it read through a linked list to find if any of the links have a certain name so it can be removed. However, if the link is at the end, the first link in the list will take its place and so the second link becomes the first one. A diagram would look like this:

A->B->C->D->E and should become B->C->D->A

This is what I worked on. I am able to make it so that any links in the middle are removed but I am stuck on this last part. Any advice would be great.

```
STUDENT *DeleteByLastName(STUDENT *students, char *name)
{
  STUDENT *pHead = students;
  STUDENT *prev = NULL;
  int check;

  pHead = pHead->Next;

  while(strcmp(pHead->Lastname, name) != 0 && pHead->Next != NULL){
    prev = pHead;
    pHead = pHead->Next;
  }
  check = strcmp(pHead->Lastname, name);
  if (check == 0){
    prev->Next = pHead->Next;
    return students;
  }
  else if (check != 0 && pHead->Next != NULL){
   prev = pHead;
   pHead = pHead->Next;

   check = strcmp(pHead->Lastname, name);
      if (check == 0){
         pHead = students;
         prev->Next = pHead;
         pHead->Next = NULL;  
         students = students->Next;
         return students;
      }
  }
```

Edit: To help clarify my issue. So my main problem is that I am having trouble trying to loop the end of the linked-list to the first element and separating it to make the B->C->D->A format. I was thinking of adding structs to save the locations of the beginning and where I want to loop back to. But this either causes my program to fail or go in an infinite loop.

Edit2: The main body of the code was provided and I was to edit functions to help complete tasks. The first one was to scan each link to see if a person's last name was in it and remove that link. Then I am to build upon the code I wrote to make conditions if the name weren't in any of the links I am suppose to make it return to the beginning. And the last task was to make the A-B-C-D-E become B-C-D-A.

Edit3: An example of how it should work:
Sanka->Robbert->Jordan->Blunc->Wei->Zhu 
and the name to be checked is Zhu, so the final list should look like this:
Robbert->Jordan->Blunc->Wei->Sanka

Comment: "I am stuck". Explain why you are stuck. You have told us what you want to do but have not explained why it is you can't do it. And what is the state of the above code? Does it do some of what you want? Does it attempt to do everything but crashes? Does it...?

Comment: kind of an odd requirement .. what's the point in rotating the first node to last?

Comment: What primitives have you got to help you?  Do you have a 'remove first' function?  A 'remove last' function?  An 'add at end function'?  With those three plus a 'delete unlinked node' function, you can do the job pretty easily.  What about the special cases?  A two-link list is special; you end up with the first node as the only node.  A one-link list is special; do you end up with the list you started with, because you removed the tail and then added it to the tail of the resulting empty list?

Comment: O sorry. So my main problem is that I am having trouble trying to loop the end of the linked-list to the first element and separating it to make the B->C->D->A format. I was thinking of adding structs to save the locations of the beginning and where I want to loop back to. But this either causes my program to fail or go in an infinite loop.

Comment: Please edit the extra information into the question — and it's not a bad idea to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]) that can build your canonical 5-element list and then execute your 'remove last and move first to last' code.

Comment: @JMei also remember every time you remove a node from the list and fail to `free` the memory associated with it, you have lost the pointer to it on return and have created a memory leak.

Comment: you can simply write code to add new node at the end which has same data as first node. then delete first node and make second node a head node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I will do:-

Your Linked List goes like this:-

A -> B -> C -> D -> E

Output should be :- B -> C -> D -> A

First of all,iterate through the link list and maintain 2 pointers, One at the start (currentPtr), keep this stable and one at the end(tailPtr), move this using a loop.

Copy the string of currentPtr to tailPtr using `strcpy(tailPtr -> name, currentPtr -> name)`.

So the linked list now looks like

A -> B -> C -> D -> A

Now, simply you just have to delete the first node by breaking it's link to B, but before that you must update your head to Node B. So `head = currentPtr -> next`(which is B Node) and afterwards setting it to NULL for avoiding illegal memory access `currentPtr -> next = NULL` (currentPtr pointing to A) and finally freeing it `free(currentPtr)`.

Output: head -> B -> C -> D -> A

Answer (score 1):

Just store your first STUDENT and link it later.

```
STUDENT *DeleteLastAndMoveFirstToLast(STUDENT *students)
{
  STUDENT *pFirst = students;
  STUDENT *pHead = pFirst->Next;

  if (!pHead) return 0;

  STUDENT *pNext = pHead;
  STUDENT *pNextAfterNext = pNext->Next;

  if (pNextAfterNext) {
    while (pNextAfterNext->Next) {
      pNext = pNext->Next;
      pNextAfterNext = pNext->Next;
    }
  }

  pNext->Next = pFirst;
  pFirst->Next = 0;
  return pHead;
}
```